# Asp .Net Core Caching select ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I went through the docs from Microsoft about caching but i still can't understand how am i supposed to do this using ajax.

HTML:

```
<select id="paragens" class="custom-select">
  <option value="">Selecione uma Paragem</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetParagensPlaneadas","Paragens")',
    type: 'get',
    success: OnSuccessParagensPlaneadas,
    error: OnError
});
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult GetParagensPlaneadas()
{
    var paragensPlaneadas = _context.ParagensPlaneadas.ToList();
    return new JsonResult(paragensPlaneadas);
}
```

I saw there's a HTML tag helper for cache which made me even more confused if i have to do it on server side or client side.

If anyone can give me some tips or at least lead me in the right direction i would appreciate thank you.

Answer (score 0):

User `OutputCache` attribute, you can decide whether cache result in client or server side depending on use case

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location=OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
public IActionResult GetParagensPlaneadas()
{
    var paragensPlaneadas = _context.ParagensPlaneadas.ToList();
    return new JsonResult(paragensPlaneadas);
}
```

more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs